# Diameter of a convex body relative to its Legendre ellipsoid

Tags: convex-geometry

Given a convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is symmetric with respect to the origin, let us measure its diameter with respect to the Euclidean metric determined by its own Legendre ellipsoid. How large can this diameter be? Is there a known sharp upper bound?

Comment: You're essentially trying to bound an "affine diameter" from above by the volume of the body. This is more or less a reverse affine isoperimetric inequality. There are not many known sharp inequalities of this type.

Answer (score 3):

There are different notions of legendre ellipsoid depending on whether you have a background   euclidean structure on the space (and in this case you also have an additional possibily because you may  divide say by a volume, or not), or if you   have no background euclidean structure     and you first construct the legendre ellipsoid  on the cotangent space and then take its dual in the tangent space (how it is done in [V. D. Milman, A. Pajor,  Lecture Notes in Math., 1376, Springer,1989] or in  http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/1104.1647).

In the second case, there are some estimations in 
http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/1408.6401 both in the symmetric and nonsymmetriccase

In the first case, one can get better results using the classically known formulas how  compare the norm given by the convex body and by its John and Loevner ellipsoids (some references are also in http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/1408.6401). I do not remember  by hart whether in the symmetric case  they have exact estimations.

Comment: Indeed, the more natural interpretation of the question is the second one, where the Legendre ellipsoid lies in the vector space dual to the one containing the body.

Comment: Aren't you confusing the Binet and the Legendre ellipsoids? The Binet Ellipsoid is in the dual space and the Legendre ellipsoid is its dual, in the same space as the convex body.

Comment: Ach. I can't keep the names straight.

Comment: Juan Carlos, what is your definition of the legendre ellipsoid?